# Plotly interactivity with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Trying to get the first [example](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/) from plotly with ggplot2 to work, I get the following error:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(plotly)

dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)

ggplotly()
```

> ggplotly()
> Error in ggplot_build2(p) : could not find function "calculate_stats"

The chart renders, but there is no interactivity.  I'm using plotly version 2.0.3 and ggplot version 2.0.0 (in RStudio v 0.99.486).  Is there a specific installation step I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: it's working for me with interactivity. In R studio Version 0.99.486

Comment: @MLavoie did you install plotly from github, or just with install.packages('plotly')

Comment: I don't remember but here's my version  plotly_2.0.3 and ggplot2 ggplot2_1.0.1

Comment: Hmmm.... thanks for the info, I'm still looking around....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed the issue:

```
install.packages("plotly", type = "source")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the devtools installation of plotly:

```
remove.packages('plotly') # if you've installed it before
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
library('plotly')

dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
qplot(carat, price, data=dsamp, colour=clarity)

ggplotly()
```